# post tag texonomy rename getting error

Tags: custom-post-types

I have tried to rename my post tag by this code, but i am getting this error:

> Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$no_terms in
>   /var/www/new/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-posts-list-table.php on line
>   1107

my code:

```
<?php  

function rename_texonomy_tag()
{
    global $wp_taxonomies;
    $wp_taxonomies['post_tag']->labels = (object)array(
        'name' => 'Groups',
        'menu_name' => 'Groups',
        'singular_name' => 'Group',
        'search_items' => 'Search Groups',
        'popular_items' => 'Popular Groups',
        'all_items' => 'All Groups',
        'parent_item' => null, // Tags aren't hierarchical
        'parent_item_colon' => null,
        'edit_item' => 'Edit Groups',
        'update_item' => 'Update Groups',
        'add_new_item' => 'Add new Groups',
        'new_item_name' => 'New Groups Name',
        'separate_items_with_commas' => 'Separata Groups with commas',
        'add_or_remove_items' => 'Add or remove Groups',
        'choose_from_most_used' => 'Choose from the most used Groups',
    );

    $wp_taxonomies['post_tag']->label = 'Groups';
}

?>
```

Comment: Format your questions, Hossain.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be careful overriding the entire array as WordPress may add new items from time to time...override each specific value instead like this:

```
add_action( 'init', function() {

    global $wp_taxonomies;

    $wp_taxonomies['post_tag']->labels->name = 'Groups';
    $wp_taxonomies['post_tag']->labels->menu_name = 'Groups';
    $wp_taxonomies['post_tag']->labels->singular_name = 'Group';
    $wp_taxonomies['post_tag']->labels->search_items = 'Search Groups';

    $wp_taxonomies['post_tag']->label = 'Groups';

}, 1 );
```

I showed a few examples just do it for all the values you wish to change.